# Disable stdout in Windows commands

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, stdout

Is there a way to disabled the stdout in a windows command specifically the `net start/stop spooler` command?

Comment: You can't disable it, but you can redirect it to the plughole: `net start spooler >nul:`. You can also redirect `stderr`, as described [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Comment: @AFH that still outputs something `NET START [service]` for starting and `NET STOP service` for starting, is there a way I can prevent it from outputting anything?

Comment: I told you: you can redirect `stderr` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way I can prevent it from outputting anything?

Redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `nul`, as follows:

```
net start spooler 2>&1 >nul

net stop spooler 2>&1 >nul
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.